# Is there a way MPMovieplayerViewController can detect if video is a stream?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller, http-live-streaming

I'm making an iOS video player application that gets a whole bunch of URLs of videos from a web service and plays them in an `MPMoviePlayerViewController`.

Most of the videos are just .mp4 or .mov files, but some of them are live HTTP streams. The only thing I have is a URL and those don't indicate whether it's a file or stream.

Since I'm using `MPMovieControlStyleNone` and my own video controls, I need to be able to detect whether or not a video is a file or a live stream in order to change my controls.

Is there any way I can detect that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an HTTP HEAD request. If the Content-Type is `application/vnd.apple.mpegurl`, then it's an http live streaming stream.